# How to substitute one variable on another in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have two arrays in Angular JS:

```
$scope.books = [];
$scope.old_books = [];
```

Also there is `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in books"></div>
<div ng-click="Do()"></div>
```

How to substitute variable `books` on `old_books` and use the same `ng-repeat` when I do click `Do()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to swap between the two different array sources of `ng-repeat`, you could do so in a couple of ways:

**1.** use a function to return the source array

In the controller:

```
var books = [], old_books = []; // don't need to set them on $scope
$scope.getBooks = function(){
   return $scope.isOldBooks ? old_books : books;
}
```

and the View uses `getBooks()` as the source:

```
<div ng-click="isOldBooks = !isOldBooks">toggle new/old</div>
<div ng-repeat="item in getBooks()">
  {{item}}
</div>
```

**2.** directly in the View

```
<div ng-click="isOldBooks = !isOldBooks">toggle new/old</div>
<div ng-repeat="item in ((isOldBooks && old_books) || books)">
  {{item}}
</div>
```

(you can preset `isOldBooks` in the controller)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you want the swapping of two variable. That is what you want.

You need to use `angular.copy` while copying one variable to another that will create a `clone` object of current object.

```
$scope.do = function(){
   var temp_var = angular.copy($scope.old_books)
   $scope.old_books = angular.copy(books);
   $scope.books = angular.copy(temp_var)
}
```